# FIWARE Cygnus sink to Elasticsearch/Kibana ?

Tags: elasticsearch, fiware-cygnus

I'm currently having a working flow :

Fiware Orion -> Fiware Cygnus -> Kafka -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch -> Kibana

I would like to push directly data from Cygnus to Elasticsearch, is there a sink available already ?

An Apache Flume/Elasticsearch sink already exist : https://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.3.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/sink/elasticsearch/ElasticSearchSink.html

I was wondering if it would be easy to use it for Cygnus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Cygnus 1.5.0 (included) such a sink could be perfectly used (as any other Flume sink) in a Cygnus agent configuration.

From 1.6.0 (included, this is the last version) you will not be able since we internally replaced the usage of native `Event` objects  with custom `NGSIEvent` ones. Why?:

- An `Event` is a set of headers and an array of raw bytes for the body.
- `NGSIEvent` inherits from `Event`and is a set of headers, an already parsed version of the body (as an object) and **an array of raw bytes for the body pointing to `null`** (this last part is the one avoiding compatibility with native Flume sinks).

Anyway, this is "easy" to fix: new version a `NGSIEvent` will containg both the parsed version of the body and the body itself as raw bytes.

Comment: Any idea when the new cygnus version containing the fix will be released? Thanks!

Comment: It was released a wekk ago: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/releases/tag/1.7.0 Sorry for not telling here.